# MySQL privileges applied for the triggers on a non-privileged user's action

Tags: mysql, triggers, privilege

I am creating a fresh schema for a new project, My basic requirements are 2 users with different privileges. One is a regular user and have minimum privileges and other is the administrator who have some elevated privileges than the regular user.

I am taking this scenario for the instance:

`basicUser have INSERT Privilege over Table1 but`**`NO`**`Privilege over Table2 and Table3`

`adminUser have INSERT Privilege over All the tables`

Now, `Table1` have a Trigger defined for `INSERT` option which INSERT the records into Table2 and Table3 taking the values from Table1 as soon as the record is inserted into table1.

I am wondering whether the trigger will work when `basicUser` insert the data into `Table1` ?
Remember He can insert the data in Table1 but He have no privilege over other tables being populated by the trigger, and this trigger is raised by `basicUser's` action.

My first guess is Yes! This should work. but I am not sure. Please correct me if I am wrong.

If yes, then is there any way I can prevent the trigger's action if the record is inserted by `basicUser` ?
I'll need a fail-safe workaround because I still need Table1 to hold the record inserted by `basicUser` but I dont want it to insert the data into other tables.

and if No, Then is there any way I can log some of `basicUser's` action, bearing in mind that He have No privilege over the table which is being used for storing logs ?

Comment: Ok, Just confirmed that the trigger will work in any condition regardless of the privilege the user have. But I still doubt whether it will work regardless of the user who created it ? I mean, If I dont have `INSERT` privilege over `Table2` but I have `TRIGGER` privilege over `Table1` and I create a trigger on `Table1` to insert data into `Table2` will it work ?? So confused O_o